# ImageButton event not firing on only one page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem on one page in my entire solution where it seems the on click event for the image button is not firing.Firstly let me describe the relevant parts of the website.
There is a total of four pages involved in this problem.Pages A-D.

I start on Page A from which I navigate to Page B via an ImageButton which works.Here some data is captured and I navigate further to Page C via another ImageButton which works.On Page C I have two ImageButtons,these are the ones giving me trouble.One is simply supposed to take me back to Page A and the other takes me to Page D.The one that takes me to Page D I send some arguments along.

Now if I click on either of these I get taken back to Page A,however when debugging even on the one thats supposed to take me back I cant see the code being hit.Here is how I have my buttons defined in the aspx page:

```html
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/backBtn.jpg" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/nextBtn.png" />
```

And my code behind for them is as follows:

```vb
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
    Response.Redirect("pageA.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
    Response.Redirect("pageD.aspx?option=4&ref=" & lblInfo.Text)
End Sub
```

The buttons aren't in a update panel.Things I have tried to do to fix this :

Remove them and readd them from scratch.
Turn into normal asp:Button to see if its a problem with ImageButtons,problem was still there.
Set AutoEventWireUp to true.
Explicitly set OnClick in aspx to the method.
Set CausesValidation to false.

None of the above has worked.If anyone can help I would be very gratefull.

Comment: As a side note, if you button is only redirecting to another page, you should replace your `ImageButton` by a simpler `Image` control, with a `NavigateUrl` property. This will avoid a double request to your server: the 1st POST to handle the postback, then the actual redirect. In opposition, a "simple" link will directly redirect the user to the target page. For cases where you require some extra data (from a textbox for example), you can handle this using a bit of javascript (but a bit of work actually).

Comment: did you set post back url for image button?

Comment: I have read elsewhere aswell that I need to set my PostBackUrl,though I am unclear on what to set it to.Also none of the other ImageButtons in my solution have it set so I didn't think it would cause my problem.

Comment: No url rewriting or default document involved ? Could it be some code in pageC or some base class, which triggers on postback before click-events handling, and redirects to page A ? (maybe some eror handling which redirects to pageA)

Comment: No url rewriting.I don't know what you mean by default document,but I do use a master page,but there is absolutely no vb code in it's codebehind.The aspx is only a base template for layout.As for code in pageC,the only code here other than the two buttons codebehind is code that executes on page load with if not isPostBack around.

Comment: @jbl please post you comment as answer so I can mark it as the answer.Your comment lead me to the problem.Instead of code on PageC which was causing the problem,it was infact code on PageB which throws an exception.After this it's redirected to PageC.Then when I click the button it checks for a cookie due to some pageload code which runs again which does not exist due to exception.This then redirects back to pageA.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No url rewriting or default document involved ?

Could it be some code in pageC or some base class, which triggers on postback before click-events handling, and redirects to page A ? 
(maybe some error handling which redirects to pageA)